Patriarchy, Matriarchy and Hinduism
Is Hinduism a patriarchal religion? Or is it matriarchal? If it not either patriarchal or matriarchal, are there 'Sampradayas' which are patriarchal and 'Sampradayas' which are matriarchal? If so, which 'Sampradayas' are those?

Hinduism (shakta sect) is the only religion in the world which worships the supreme personality of godhead as feminine. so what do you think?
